# why there is not a "unique and general way" to create an instance from Classes in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, drag-and-drop

I am familiar with android components (Activity , Service , Broadcast Receiver and Content Provider).
why there is not a uniform and general pattern to use from different android services (such as sms,Bluetooth,Camera,...)?
when we want to use from them in our Activities,there is several way to define an instance from these classes.

for example:

```
//using from Bluetooth in our app:

BluetoothAdapter obj = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);


//using from Camera in our app:
```

//1. we can use from CameraManager API

//2. we can use from Intent:

```
    Intent obj = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

    // using from call in our app:

    TelephonyManager obj = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    // using from SMS in our app:
```

//1. using from `SmsManager API`

//2. using from Intent and use from Messaging app in our device:

```
    Intent obj = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

    //using from Email in our app:

    Intent obj = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
```

Why there is not a uniform way?
for example:
1. in all of them, we use from `getSystemService`!

Or

2. we use from:

// Bluetooth: 
intent obj = new Intent(Context.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_ACCESS)

// Camera: Intent obj = new Intent(Context.ACTION_CAMERA_ACCESS)

// SMS : Intent obj = new Intent(Context.ACTION_SMS_ACCESS)

// Email : Intent obj = new Intent(Context.ACTION_EMAIL_ACCESS)

//Call : Intent obj = new Intent(Context.ACTION_CALL_ACCESS)

please clarify me...

Comment: I dont understand what does not make sense, one way you use an Intent that launches another app and another way lets you do stuff right from your app

Comment: I think you need to read up on intents, and in particular what those intents are doing. Creating an action intent tells Android you have the intent to perform an action, but you need help from an outside source in doing so (e.g. I need to take a picture but my app doesn't have that functionality built in). ____Manager allows you to make use of the SDK, libraries, etc. to perform actions inside of your application without help from outside applications (e.g. I need to take a picture, and I have created the functionality to do so within my app).

Comment: I mean that why android does not use from the following expressions:                                                                        // Bluetooth:  intent obj = new Intent(Context.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_ACCESS)                    // Camera:  Intent obj = new Intent(Context.ACTION_CAMERA_ACCESS)                         // SMS : Intent obj = new Intent(Context.ACTION_SMS_ACCESS)                                // Email : Intent obj = new Intent(Context.ACTION_EMAIL_ACCESS)                             //Call : Intent obj = new Intent(Context.ACTION_CALL_ACCESS)